# What tech is better for infographics and data visualization project?

Tags: graphics, visualization, data-visualization

I would like to visualize sales data from various stores. I think the visualization should have two parts:

- Map: Show a map with pan/zoom controls allowing users to see sales info gathered in different areas.
- Data Tables: Just bunch of standard data grids with paging/filtering.

Can anyone suggest frameworks or libraries for creating something like this? I'd prefer something that works with Borland Delphi or the .NET Framework. At this point I don't know whether it should be a desktop or web app.

Comment: Have you checked this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software)?

Comment: @bacchus Thanks for the list. I will check it out later.

Answer (score 4):

I would expose my data in a common format, like JSON. This enables you to integrate with a [plethora of JavaScript-based data visualization tools](http://selection.datavisualization.ch/) which understands JSON. This readies you for the web, especially considering SVG rendering is becoming more widely supported in browsers. And, if you need to do a desktop app, you can always wrap your webapp up as an SPA (e.g. distributing it as a Chrome plugin).

Answer (score 2):

I would use Raphael.js & jQuery in order to draw the map and add some interactivity.

http://jquery.com/
http://raphaeljs.com/

And by the way, some example (in French) I made using both : http://www.quicumule.fr

In this example, I used PHP to generate the javascript. You can also generate a JSON table with PHP and your datas stored in a Database. Then, you use Raphael & jQuery to make it fancy.

If you need further help, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: it is certainly true that client offers more powerful framework but we can see strong growth of the API/frameworks on web based technologies. also worth noticing that web is the future, ^_^ that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Choosel Mashup Framework](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/) or take a look at how it is built.  You can see a [video online](http://vimeo.com/16109235#) that shows you how to use it and a [demo website](http://choosel-mashups.appspot.com/) to play with.  There is an [application to search for rental places](http://victoria.rentalmap.co/) that was built based on the choosel in a short period of time.

It is written in Java (with GWT), so if you definitively want something for .NET, you can see and learn how Choosel was built.